# why a vertical white band appears after saving/exporting from print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a problem with my map composer. After exporting images a white strip appears on my map. How can I fix that?

[image: just why :(]

Answer (score 1):

May be with a lower export resolution, i.e. 200 dpi (export settings)?

If your image come form an online source, you can also tri to save the image on your disk first (Menu "project - Save map as image")

Edit:

You also have the possibility to test other backgrounds. You have some with the Extension "Open Layers Plugin". I have tested the google's image and it seems good:

[image]

An other possibility is to download other background (i.e. with SASPlanet)

Comment: THX for the answer, i lowered dpi to 200 and the strip moved slightly to the right :D but when i lowered dpi to 100 it was fine, the strip is gone... but the resolution sux :(  But then i had an idea, why not to increase dpi to 400 and the secound strip appears. But if i change map background (or layout - not sure how it is in english) in seems fine, but it is not so pretty.